# HTC Desire stuck on HBOOT

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, 2.2-froyo, htc-desire

I've been researching possible issues and fixes for the last couple of hours now and not turning up much, so I have a HTC Desire stuck on HBOOT with unresponsive buttons when attempting to select fastboot etc.

So far from what I have turned up I have found that it isn't possible to restore the phone to a clean install of 2.2/2.3 version of Android without the phone already being rooted, am I correct with this? Or have I missed something in my haste to solve this?

If I have left any important information out please let me know so I can correct this.

Comment: It's not clear what you've tried, why, and what happened.  What happens, for example, if you don't "...attempt to select fastboot etc"?  Can you reboot into the phone normally?  Do you have a recovery installed?  What procedure were you following?  I put CM on my Desire and I seem to recall having to run a few steps first; root, recovery, s-off, putting a different HBOOT down to rearrange the way disk space was partitioned etc.  Without more details I'm not sure what help you can expect to receive.

Comment: Sorry for being so vague.

The phone was given to me after a friend returned from an outting saying he went to sleep after turning phone off, woke up and turned it back on and it was then just stuck on HBOOT.

I am unable to select anything at all on the HBOOT screen and the phone will not boot up normally, when in HBOOT the only thing that shows me it's still alive is connecting a USB cable.

I've not done anything so far, as I've been unable to do anything either with the phone or connecting via USB to my computer, phone is picked up via windows but is failing to install correctly.